# Print multidimensional Mat in OpenCV (C++)

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

In the OpenCV Tutorial

http://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d6d/tutorial_mat_the_basic_image_container.html

is the following example for creating a Mat.

```
int sz[3] = {2,2,2};
Mat L(3,sz, CV_8UC(1), Scalar::all(0));
```

This works fine, but when i try to print the Mat my programm crashes.

```
cout << "L = " << endl << " " << L << endl << endl;
```

Why doesn't this work ? 
Is there a way to do this without loops or splitting the Mat L ?

Comment: what error message, if any, is shown when you crash?

Comment: As far as i know there is no overload of << operator for multidimensional array. The only solution is to print matrix slices

Comment: @hammeramr error message probably is that dims<=2 is not satisfied. It is opencv assert

Comment: @hammeramr the console output was `Exception thrown at 0x00007FF909679E08 in OpenCV_tutorial_coremodule_1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x000000BFD9F6D150. Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF909679E08 in OpenCV_tutorial_coremodule_1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x000000BFD9F6D150.` wich made no sense to me. However the Stacktrace pointed to std::ostream operator<< which seems to be the the problem **KamilSzelag** described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print n-dim matrix you could use Matrix slice. Since 2d matrices are stored row by row, 3d matrices plane by plane and so on, you could use code:

```
cv::Mat sliceMat(cv::Mat L,int dim,std::vector<int> _sz)
{
cv::Mat M(L.dims - 1, std::vector<int>(_sz.begin() + 1, _sz.end()).data(), CV_8UC1, L.data + L.step[0] * 0);
return M;
}
```

To perform mat slice.For more dimensions you should make more slices. Example shows 3 and 4 dimension matrices:

```
std::cout << "3 dimensions" << std::endl;

std::vector<int> sz = { 3,3,3 };

cv::Mat L;
L.create(3, sz.data(), CV_8UC1);
L = cv::Scalar(255);

std::cout<< sliceMat(L, 1, sz);

std::cout << std::endl;
std::cout <<"4 dimensions"<< std::endl;
sz = { 5,4,3,5 };
L.create(4, sz.data(), CV_8UC1);
L = cv::Scalar(255);
std::cout << sliceMat(sliceMat(L, 1, sz),2, std::vector<int>(sz.begin() + 1, sz.end()));
```

end result screen

[image]

Comment: Great answer. Can you take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46547531/how-to-estimate-and-apply-color-correction-matrix-using-a-24-block-color-card?

Comment: What is usage of `int dim` in sliceMat function?